# Where are all of the "Letters of the Lost" for the Dead Letters achievement ?

Tags: far-cry-3

How many letters are there total that I need to collect ?  Where are they located ?

Comment: If you collect one of them then go into the menu you can see all letters, with ones you haven't found locked. I think there are approximately 18. You need to buy treasure maps to unlock their locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 20 letters in total.
You can buy a map with their location at the weapons dealer.
You will be able to apply a filter for the letters specifically.

Comment: Ah thank you.  As with my other question posts, I didn't know there was the ability to purchase a map for them.  This is super easy.